# How to create a list containing the sums of the elements in each tuple?

Tags: python-3.x

I am asked to make a function that sums the elements in each tuple

```
data = [(1,2), (3, 4, 5), (10, 20, 30, 40)]
print(tuple_sums(data))
```

The result must be

```
[3, 12, 100]
```

My wrong answer is below. It can only return one sum of the tuple:

```
def tuple_sums(tuples):
    """returns a list containing the sums""" 
    thesum = 0
    for i in tuples:
        thesum = thesum + i
    return thesum
```

How can I return a list of sums instead of just one sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehensions are a cool feature:

```
[sum(x) for x in data]
# => [3, 12, 100]
```